# What is the value of ⍰?

Tags: calculation-puzzle

This is a question that I have been unable to figure out an answer to.  Moreover I can't figure out what it relates to.  It was given on a programming proficiency test.

the question mark symbol appears to be: U+2370 APL FUNCTIONAL SYMBOL QUAD QUESTION

Here is the question:

```
What is the value of ⍰ ?

    ⍰ + ⍰ = 10;
    ⍰ + ⍰ = 6;
    ⍰ + ⍰ = 5;
    
    a. 6
    b. 9
    c. 7
    d. 8
    e. 1
```

Comment: Isn't the U+2370 character drawn as a placeholder, instead of something else (e.g. an image or a TeX formula)? This might happen for example if the text rendering/displaying software encountered an error while trying to draw them.

Comment: @trolley813 Nope, that's U+FFFD, `�`. The APL symbol doesn't have those semantics. I'm guessing the question setter just looked for a boxed question mark symbol.

Comment: [You have to observe it for it to have a value.](https://www.dyalog.com/blog/2015/09/parallel-programming-with-futuresisolates/) ;-)

Comment: If it's a programming question, then what language has a single `=` assignment and no lvaues? If it's logic, why the `;` at the end of each line?

Comment: Is this.....javascript?

Answer (score 34):

I have a theory: I think that the original puzzle looked like that:

> `What is the value of � ?
>
>      � + � = 10;
>      � + � = 6;
>      � + � = 5;
>
>
>      a. 6
>      b. 9
>      c. 7
>      d. 8
>      e. 1`

� is the unicode replacement character, which was shown because the original symbols (some emoji?) could not be displayed (see [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)). So, what were the original symbols? We don't know, but we can try to make the puzzle solvable by substituting them:

> `What is the value of  ?
>
>       +  = 10;
>       +  = 6;
>       +  = 5;
>
>
>      a. 6
>      b. 9
>      c. 7
>      d. 8
>      e. 1`

Which can be answered trivially.

---

Note that this is not the only solution, another one would be, for example,

> `What is the value of  ?
>
>       +  = 10;
>       +  = 6;
>       +  = 5;`

(yielding a different solution), but that one is boring, because the third equation is not required.

Comment: +1: this definitely seems like the most likely explanation. (Also, welcome to Puzzling!)

Answer (score 9):

This is probably a bit of a stretch, but maybe

> e. 1

Reasoning:

> I noticed that the ⍰ in the question is completely identical to the first ⍰ in each equation, but not the second one. This could just be the way it shows up and irrelevant to the problem, but it could also mean that the value of ⍰ only pertains to the completely identical ⍰s. If so, and if the second ⍰s must represent positive numbers, than the answer must be 1 because it is the only option with a lesser value than all the sums of the equations.

Also:

> Even if all the ⍰s mean the same thing, I still might lean towards 1; 1 + 1 = 10 in binary, and the word "one" has 3 letters and 3 + 3 = 6. I don't see a good way to get 5 (1 *is* the 5th option but that doesn't seem like a reason that quite fits this puzzle.)

Answer (score 5):

My response:

> -4 + _

Explanation:

> Consider ⍰ as a missing part of the equation,
> in this case, when replaced, we get: -4 + _ + -4 + _ = 10
> and we can now replace spaces with numbers from the condition

And from the higher ground we see:

> ```
>      9        9
>
> -4 + _ + -4 + _ = 10
>
>      7        7
> -4 + _ + -4 + _ = 6
>
>      7        6
> -4 + _ + -4 + _ = 5
> ```